# What is a performant partitioning strategy for key-agnostic mapping?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

First of all I'm working with PySpark on Glue and I'm reading several very large CSV files. Those CSVs are bzip2 compressed and inflated several GB large.

At this stage of processing I'm only performing a simple map over all rows. No joins, group bys, filtering. Just a map.

Let's say I am working on 10 nodes. Generally speaking, would it be preferable to have a rather high number of partitions or a rather low number?

I would guess that independent of available cores on all those nodes that number should be pretty high to make sure that every executor is busy at all times having small chunks of data available.

So, let's say there are 20 cores on those 10 nodes and let's for a second assume *there are* key-based partitions then something larger than 40 would likely not be a good idea. But in the key-agnostic mapping case I'd tend to something like 1000 partitions or more.

Does that make sense? I'm especially interested in the thought process here.